# Asp.net create LinkButton and attach onclick event when another LinkButton is clicked

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

So.. I'm dynamically creating LinkButtons on my page like this:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.Click += new EventHandler(lb_Click);
```

When one of these LinkButtons is clicked, I need to know which one the links was clicked, then create another LinkButton and attach an onclick event on it. (How) can I do this? If I have understood correctly, click events can't be attached in (this case in) lb_Click function, so is there any way I still could do this?

Edited:

To make this problem more understandable, here's how I tried to make it but it does not work:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.click += new EventHandler(lb_Click);

void lb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb2 = new LinkButton();
    lb2.click += new EventHandler(lb2_Click);
}

void lb2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

Clicking lb2 does not fire the lb2_Click event.

Comment: set unique id for each link button  and check that in  link button event handler.

Comment: Did you not read what I wrote? If I create new LinkButton in lb_Click and try add new eventhandler on it, clicking the LinkButton won't launch the event. Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: How did you add the link buttons to the page?

Comment: For example: tc4.Controls.Add(lb); (tc4 is a table cell element on the page)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on `sender argument`

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.Id= "Test1";
lb.Click += new EventHandler(lb_Click);

LinkButton lb2 = new LinkButton();
lb2.Id= "Test2";
lb2.Click += new EventHandler(lb_Click);

void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   var yourControl = (LinkButton)sender;
   var id = yourControl.Id;
   if(id == "Test1")
   {
      ...
   }
   else if(id == "Test2")
   {
      ...
   }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that I the lb2 needs to be created IN LinkButton_Click and have completely different event onclick. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Yes you can execute this treatment et he can have sense, it's not problem, it's depend of your use case

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes, yes: I'm very, **very** late to the party.
*BUT* for future reference of anyone coming to this post:

Your methods are marked as `private` (omitting an access modifier defaults to `private`), which means they are not accessible enough for them to be called.

Instead, use the `protected` modifier to ensure they get called properly.

Like so:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.click += new EventHandler(lb_Click);

protected void lb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb2 = new LinkButton();
    lb2.click += new EventHandler(lb2_Click);
}

protected void lb2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

Hope this helps some future visitors :)